# Where is the value of objects like lists,ints, and strings stored?

Tags: python

Alright so all lists have `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` and ints have `__add__` `__sub__` and such to operate on their value. But where is that value actually stored / how can I reference it? Say I want to make a class imitating an list. It might look something like this

```
class Memory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [] 
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.data[i]
    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.data[key] = item
```

This isn't very efficient, and I'd have to most likely write every single method of the class individually, which can span hundreds of lines with multiple classes.

The next best solution to create the class being a child of a list like:

```
class Memory(list):
...
```

But you can't edit any of its methods because you can't reference its value. If you changes its `__setitem__()` 
What I was wanting to do with this is to create a list class so I can set the list's and do other operations values all on one lambda. I can't just simply directly call `__setitem__(key,item)` because you can't input a key outside of the range of the items already present in the list. How would I be able to edit the list's value without calling its `__setitem__()` method.

Comment: In the computer! http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/6a/6a3b31692b322eea09f6888adf1ff62f5d003c9a7d8c98e8922faaca070f4582.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question about "where is the value ... stored", and I'm not sure what you mean by "I can't just simply directly call `__setitem__(key,item)` because you can't input a key outside of the range of the items already present in the list," but if I understand you correctly, you just have to "fill in" values in between the value you want to set and the current length.

For example, I have a utility class that I sometimes use to do this.  (See the test cases at the bottom for an idea of how I use it.)

```
class DynamicArray(list):
    ''' Just like a normal list except you can skip indices when you fill it.  '''

    def __init__(self, defaultVal = None, startingCapacity = 0):
        super(DynamicArray, self).__init__()
        self.defaultVal = defaultVal
        if (startingCapacity > 0):
            self += [ defaultVal ] * startingCapacity 


    def insert(self, ind, val):
        if (ind > len(self)):
            for i in xrange(len(self), ind):
                self.append(self.defaultVal)
        super(DynamicArray, self).insert(ind, val)


    def set(self, ind, val):
        self[ind] = val


    def __setitem__(self, ind, val):
        if (ind >= len(self)):
            for i in xrange(len(self), ind + 1):
                self.append(self.defaultVal)
        super(DynamicArray, self).__setitem__(ind, val)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = DynamicArray()
    assert(len(a) == 0)
    a[3] = 2
    assert(a[3] == 2)
    assert(a[0] is None  and  a[1] is None  and  a[2] is None)
    assert(len(a) == 4)
    a[1] = 1
    assert(a[1] == 1)
    assert(a[3] == 2)
    assert(a[0] is None  and  a[2] is None)
    assert(len(a) == 4)
    a[5] = 7
    assert(a[5] == 7)
    assert(a[3] == 2)
    assert(a[1] == 1)
    assert(a[0] is None  and  a[2] is None)
    assert(len(a) == 6)
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I was looking for in the question.

Comment: @tatatat0 Sorry. If I understand your question, I'm pretty sure that the answer is that you don't have access to the actual storage in python objects like lists. These are usually implemented in C and, even if you could access them, they're conceptually "private" so it wouldn't be a good idea to "break encapsulation" anyway. My answer assumed that, failing direct access, you'd want to instead inherit from `list` and override methods like `__setitem__` (your "next best solution").  I was attempting to show you how to get around the issue that (I thought) you were hung up on there.